# Why ADO.NET still connected to SQL Server with wrong user?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

I am running Microsoft SQL Server 2014.
I try to connect to SQL Server using ADO.NET in a C# application.
My connection string is:

```
var myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data
 Source=VIRTUAL-ADMIN\\SQLEXPRESS;" +
                 "Integrated Security=SSPI;" +
                 "Initial Catalog=StudentManagement;"+
                 "User id=...;"+
                "Password=...");
```

My Initial Catalog is a right and existed database.
But my username is a wrong username!
The Password I have inserted is also wrong already.
But ADO.NET still connected to my database and I can execute query and do everything with my database.
How can I fix it?

Comment: HI, Can you try to sql profile it and see if its connecting using same user?

Comment: Thank you, my problem has been fixed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have provided both `Integrated Security=SSPI;` as well as username & password so it by default takes `integrated Security` i.e. windows authentication and thus you are able to connect with wrong credentials as well.

So, either user `Integrated Security` or your credentials as you do when connecting to SSMS, when it asks for either `Windows authentication` or `SQL Server authentication`

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx):-

> Integrated Security When false, User ID and Password are specified in
>   the connection. When true, the current Windows account credentials are
>   used for authentication.

Comment: When Integrated Security false, User ID and Password are specified in the connection. When true, the current Windows account credentials are used for authentication.